# Cmder - Change Directory color during ls

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, cmder

I am using chmder with Ubuntu for Windows 10 with zsh and oh-my-zsh. I am running the powerlevel9k theme which has a handy Git status bar as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHVxu.png).

I am using chmder color theme selection with "Solarized (Luke Maciak)". I want to change the directories color which chmder allows me to but that'll also change the "master" arrow tab. Is there any way to decouple this relation or another way to change the directory colors?

Many guides out there recommended downloading this [repo](https://github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized) and configuring .zshrc to evaluate one of the desired values as dircolors for ls. I have that but it only works on regular [Bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zz8o.png) not cmder.

I suspect that cmder color theme is overriding dircolors but I'm not sure how to go about handling that.